# Updating React-Select menu with setState?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to get React-Select to display a different dropdown menu list based on the user input:

```
const helpOptions = [
  { value: "user", label: "u:<String> User Operator" },
  { value: "day", label: "d:<Number> Date Operator" },
  { value: "week", label: "w:<Number> Week Operator" },
  { value: "month", label: "m:<Number> Month Operator" },
  { value: "bracket", label: "() Brackets Operator" },
  { value: "and", label: "&& AND Operator" },
  { value: "or", label: "|| OR Operator" },
  { value: "not", label: "~ NOT Operator" }
];

const userOptions = [
  { value: "john", label: "u:John" },
];

class Field extends Component {
  state = {
    menu: userOptions,
    value: ""
  };

  onInputChange = e => {
    if (e.substring(0, 1) === "?") {
      this.setState(
        {
          menu: helpOptions,
          value: e
        },
        () => {
          console.log(this.state.menu);
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.setState({
        menu: []
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { menu, value } = this.state;
    console.log("rendering");
    console.log(menu);
    return (
      <Select
        isMulti
        value={value}
        options={menu}
        onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The desired behavior is if the first character of the text entered into the search field is a '?' the menu will populate with the const of `helpOptions`. Otherwise it would be (for now) empty.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-sun-cfg71

From the console logs, I seem to be getting the values and the rendering seems to be working. However, I am still getting 'No Option' as a response from the React-Select component.

How can I dynamically change the React-Select menu items based on the user's input?

Comment: What is the desired behavior? Can you explain it in your question?

Comment: I have edited the question to address the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

***Update***

If you want your `state` to update after calling `setState` you need use a function that will work only after updating the state:

```
this.setState(state => ({
  ...state,
  menu: helpOptions
}));
```

---

First of all you need to call a [constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) in your component. Secondly, in [documentation](https://react-select.com/home) to `react-select` prop `value` doesn't exist. Thirdly, it’s good practice to copy your state before changing.

Here is a valid code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import "./styles.css";

const helpOptions = [
  { value: "user", label: "u:<String> User Operator" },
  { value: "day", label: "d:<Number> Date Operator" },
  { value: "week", label: "w:<Number> Week Operator" },
  { value: "month", label: "m:<Number> Month Operator" },
  { value: "bracket", label: "() Brackets Operator" },
  { value: "and", label: "&& AND Operator" },
  { value: "or", label: "|| OR Operator" },
  { value: "not", label: "~ NOT Operator" }
];

const userOptions = [
  { value: "john", label: "u:John" },
  { value: "stan", label: "d:Stan" },
  { value: "addison", label: "w:Addison" },
  { value: "dionis", label: "m:Dionis" }
];

class Field extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      menu: userOptions,
      value: ""
    };
  }

  onInputChange = e => {
    if (e.substring(0, 1) === "?") {
      console.log("help");
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        menu: helpOptions
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        menu: userOptions
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { menu, value } = this.state;

    return <Select isMulti options={menu} onInputChange={this.onInputChange} />;
  }
}

export default Field;
```

Here is an example on [codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-surf-qkgig?file=/src/Field.jsx:0-1313)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm looking to change the menu options based on the user input i.e. any string with a '?' as the first character will show the helpOptions instead of the userOptions. Sorry if the question was not clear.

Comment: @Carrein, ```setState``` calls are asynchronous, so you should not expect ```this.state``` to display the new value instantly after calling ```setState```. You need to add a function that will work only after updating the state, if you need to get a new value based on the current state.